# accordion panel should not open on if condition - coffeescript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, coffeescript, accordion

I have an accordion in my `.html.slim` file having two panels.

- `Panel 1` has a checkbox with some T&Cs text.
- `Panel 2` has anything

  ```
  #accordion.panel-group aria-multiselectable="true" role="tablist"

    .panel.panel-default
      #headingStepOne.panel-heading role="tab"
        .panel-title
          a.collapsed aria-controls="collapseStepOne" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseStepOne" role="button"
            | Panel 1
      #collapseStepOne.panel-collapse.collapse.in aria-labelledby="headingStepOne" role="tabpanel"
        .panel-body
          .row
            input[
              id='my-checkbox'
              name='my-checkbox'
              type='checkbox'
              value='my-text'
              required='true'
            ]
            text.mar-left-12 Accept Terms & Conditions

    .panel.panel-default
      #headingStepTwo.panel-heading role="tab"
        .panel-title
          a.collapsed aria-controls="collapseStepTwo" aria-expanded="true" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseStepTwo" role="button"
            | Panel 2
      #collapseStepTwo.panel-collapse.collapse aria-labelledby="headingStepTwo" role="tabpanel"
        .panel-body
          .row
            label something
  ```

**Requirement:**

- Panel 2 should not open until user not checked the checkbox in panel 1.

**CoffeeScript**

```
$(document).on 'click', '.panel-heading', (e) ->
  panel = $(this).find('a').attr('href')
  if panel == '#collapseStepTwo' && !$('#my-checkbox').is(':checked')
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    return
  $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide')
  $(panel).collapse('show');
```

**Issue:**

On clicking `Panel 2` when checkbox in panel 1 is not checked, it is coming inside `if condition` and return but still opening `Panel 2` while keeping the panel 1 remain open.
Which means that `Panel 2` is not opening from  `$(panel).collapse('show');` because if the control not return from if condition `$('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide')` should close panel 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Bootstrap has its event listeners bind to accordion.

You can stop those listeners from triggering by stopping event propagation.

In your case, you are trying to stop propagation of `click` event, but bootstrap has its own events which are triggered when accordion is opened or closed.

You can do something like this

```
$(document).on "show.bs.collapse", "#collapseStepTwo, (e) ->
  if !$('#my-checkbox').is(':checked')
    e.stopPropagation()
```

You can learn more about Bootstrap accordion here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-events